# Information about PARSE and TRY_PARSE function in Denali CTP 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I know that among the various functions introduced in Denali CTP 3, there are two

as PARSE and TRY_PARSE. But I have not seen any information about those...
Could anyone please let me know about the same?

Comment: My local development instance says it's version 11.0.3000 (that's a Denali version if I [understand this page correctly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185#bookmark-sqlserver2012)) but when I attempt to use TRY_PARSE in my query, it says that function is not available

Comment: my SQL Mgt Studio is 2008 R2, so, IDK if that influences my intellisense, but, looks like the query works. I also set the compat mode [per this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22310882)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126(SQL.110).aspx

Comment: +1 That's TRY_PARSE, PARSE is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316(v=SQL.110).aspx