# TRY_CONVERT fails on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following SQL statement fails on SQL Server 2012(SP1) 11.0.3401.0 Version

```
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(10) = '12312.2'
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),@b)
```

error message

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'DECIMAL' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

But works fine on SQL Server 2012(SP1) 11.0.3393.0

Both servers have no problem with `TRY_PARSE()`

```
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(10) = '12312.2'
SELECT TRY_PARSE(@b AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

**Update:**

after further testing and trying conversion to different types got another different error message

```
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(10) = '12312'
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT,@b)
```

Error:

```
error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

So original error message was miss leading, but now I'm even more confused why it is not there.

Comment: Works fine for me on 11.0.3401.0 http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fge8p.png

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check that the database compatibility level for the particular database you are using the function in is set to `SQL Server 2012 (110)` under `properties/options/compatibility level` for the database.

Comment: You got it. One database was set to 110 and it was working fine but another one was set to 100.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Happy to have helped :)

Comment: You could use the following statement to change the compatibility level:  
`ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = { 90 | 100 | 110 | 120 } `  

Refer msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

Comment: Is that something that can be changed after creating the database? I know it sounds silly but the field on my case is disabled. Permissions issue maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have specified on which database you want to run the query on.

```
use [Database_Name]
go    
>>>>query here <<<
go
```

In my case I had a number of different databases on the server with different compatibility levels.

Answer (score 1):

**You can run the following script to Upgrade your database compatibility level to SQL Server 2012 (110):**

```
if (SELECT  compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '[Your_Database_Name]')<120 
begin
ALTER DATABASE StreamNet
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL= 110
end
```

**Note**: Replace [Your_Database_Name] with your current database name.

**Reference**: [See Microsoft solution for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Using%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio,-To%20view%20or&text=Right%2Dclick%20the%20database%2C%20and,the%20Compatibility%20level%20list%20box.)

Answer (score 0):

Try another IDE or environment to see if isolates the error?  I was getting this error running a query in Azure Data Studio.  When I ran the same query in SQL Server Management Studio -- where I'd first written it -- it ran successfully.