# MSSQL 2012 - Why is AVG & TRY_CONVERT not returning the correct value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I am using MSSQL 2012 and I am trying to use `AVG` together with `TRY_CONVERT` on a table column with the following datatype: `nvarchar(255), NOT NULL`

First before I try to query using AVG & TRY_CONVERT, this is the data that I want to get the AVG value out of using this query:

[image: SQL Results before using AVG and TRY_CONVERT]
And this is the results after using AVG and TRY_CONVERT, 0 rows returned.

[image: Results after AVG & TRY_CONVERT]
I also tried to use a subquery then i got 18 row returned, but with value NULL, i skipped out on AVG just to see if i was getting the correct values.. but it seems not, i also included the p.serialnumber column to show that its the correct rows that was returned, its just the value NULL that somehow appears after TRY_CONVERT.

[image]

**UPDATE!:**

When I execute the query below which target data that has a "." separator (qtv2.qtv_qteid = 58 (instead of 63)) , it works! So the issue is the "," separator. Anyone know solution to this??

```
declare @ProjectSelection nvarchar(10)
set @ProjectSelection = 'C82007588'


SELECT AVG(TRY_CONVERT(numeric(10,5), avgcap))
FROM 
(
select qtv2.qtv_result as avgcap
from ProductionOrder PO
left join CustomerOrder co on co.CustomerOrderId=po.customerorderid
left join ProductionOrderProperty pop on pop.ProductionOrderId=po.productionorderid
left join product p on p.ProductionOrderId=po.productionorderid
left join QualityTestValues qtv on qtv.qtv_productid=p.ProductId
left join QualityTestValues qtv2 on qtv2.qtv_productId=p.ProductId

where pop.Value=@ProjectSelection and pop.name = 'project' and po.ProductTypeId = 1
and qtv2.qtv_qteid = 58 and qtv2.qtv_valid = 1 and qtv.qtv_ProductSegmentId = 144 and qtv.qtv_valid = 1
and qtv.qtv_qteid = 51 and qtv.qtv_result = 'J'

group by co.CustomerName, pop.Value, qtv2.qtv_result, p.SerialNumber
) A
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
22.200000
```

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (You can't copy and paste images into your dbms editor...)

Comment: I can't read your images.  Remove them, and add a minimal query as _text_.

Comment: Perhaps some problem with decimal separator - comma versus point?

Comment: @Arvo you may be correct here, i tried to use the query and target data that has values like this:  22.200000 and that works, so the problem is the comma separator in these values that im trying to use TRY_CONVERT on.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: `replace()` function may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your first query and do something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(TRY_CONVERT(numeric(10,5), avgcap))
FROM 
(
    -- Insert your first query here.
) A
```

This should give you the average of the numbers.

**EDIT**

Here is a workable example that should return 24.000000.

```
SELECT AVG(TRY_CONVERT(numeric(10,5), A))
FROM 
(
    SELECT '22.5' AS A
    UNION
    SELECT '23.5' AS A
    UNION
    SELECT '26.0' AS A
) B
```

Comment: Hi Danieboy, i have tested this and it returns 1 value and its NULL.

Comment: Using the first query you posted as inner? The one that returned all the values.

Comment: @Mikael try to run the example I provided.

Answer (score 0):

How about your compatibility level? A similar question can be found here:

[TRY_CONVERT fails on SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310486/try-convert-fails-on-sql-server-2012)

Although your server version is 2012, a lower compatibility level can cause the try_convert to be unavailable for use in your database. You can check this by running the following code in your specific database and afterwards on for instance the master database.

```
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(10) = '12312'
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT,@b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, using TRY_PARSE instead of TRY_CONVERT.

```
DECLARE @ProjectSelection nvarchar(10)
SET @ProjectSelection = 'C82007588'


SELECT AVG(avgcap) as avgcap
FROM 
(
    SELECT qtv2.qtv_result, TRY_PARSE( qtv2.qtv_result AS NUMERIC(10,3)) avgcap
    FROM ProductionOrder PO
        LEFT JOIN CustomerOrder co on co.CustomerOrderId=po.customerorderid
        LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderProperty pop on pop.ProductionOrderId=po.productionorderid
        LEFT JOIN product p on p.ProductionOrderId=po.productionorderid
        LEFT JOIN QualityTestValues qtv on qtv.qtv_productid=p.ProductId
        LEFT JOIN QualityTestValues qtv2 on qtv2.qtv_productId=p.ProductId
    WHERE pop.Value=@ProjectSelection 
        AND pop.name = 'project' 
        AND po.ProductTypeId = 1
        AND qtv2.qtv_qteid = 63 
        AND qtv2.qtv_valid = 1 
        AND qtv.qtv_ProductSegmentId = 144 
        AND qtv.qtv_valid = 1
        AND qtv.qtv_qteid = 51 
        AND qtv.qtv_result = 'J'
    GROUP BY co.CustomerName, pop.Value, qtv2.qtv_result, p.SerialNumber
) A`
```

Results:
avgcap
21264.850000